# Flatten routes tree

Tags: javascript, recursion, tree

I'm trying to find a way to flatten out an array with routes (vanilla js), and child routes so that I get an array with objects at the same level, but with with their `name` and `path` property is based on their "level".

For example I would like `name` be something like `dashboard.settings.user.......` same goes for `path` to join together the path to a "valid" one.

I've been trying with a recursive function, but cannot figure out how to keep track of levels..

**UPDATE:**

```
var routesConfig = [
    {
        name: 'dashboard',
        path: '/dashboard',
        children: [
            {
                name: 'settings',
                path: '/settings',
                children: [
                    {
                        name: 'user',
                        path: '/user'
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'email',
                        path: '/email',
                        children: [
                            {
                                name: 'template',
                                path: '/template',
                                children: [
                                    {
                                        name: 'error',
                                        path: '/error'
                                    },
                                    {
                                        name: 'success',
                                        path: '/success'
                                    }
                                ],
                                name: 'lists',
                                path: '/lists',
                                children: [
                                    {
                                        name: 'signup',
                                        path: '/signup'
                                    },
                                    {
                                        name: 'newsletter',
                                        path: '/newsletter'
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                name: 'sender',
                                path: '/sender'
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                name: 'contact',
                path: '/contact',
                children: [
                    {
                        name: 'person',
                        path: '/person',
                        children: [
                            {
                                name: 'john',
                                path: '/john'
                            },
                            {
                                name: 'jane',
                                path: '/jane'
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
]

flattenRoutes();

function flattenRoutes(){
    let routes = [];

    routesConfig.map(route => {
        const {name, path, children} = route;
        routes.push({name, path});

        if(children && children.length){
            iterateRouteChildren(route, routes, 1, []);
        }
    });

    console.log("routes", routes);
}

function iterateRouteChildren(parent, routes, depth, tree){
    for(let i = 0; i < parent.children.length; i++){
        let childRoute = parent.children[i];

        let name = childRoute.name;
        let path = childRoute.path;

        if(depth === 1){
            tree = [];
        }else{
            tree.push(childRoute.name)

        }

        routes.push({name, path, tree: tree.filter(Boolean).join('.')});

        if(childRoute.children && childRoute.children.length){
            iterateRouteChildren(childRoute, routes, depth + 1, tree);
        }

    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Based on Nina solution, I asked for a way to keep the original objects / values, but `name` and `path` to be rewritten to their "new" values, for example route "email" should have its `name` to read: `dashboard.settings.email` and it's `path` to be rewritten to: `/dashboard/settings/email`
So mutate each object, and keep to untouched properties (but still keep it as a flat array, so no nested children array).

**UPDATE 3:**

To try to clarify. My nested routesConfig will contain objects with properties such as "name", "path", "some other property", and **maybe** "children".

I would like to flatten out the whole tree, so everything is on the same level, but all children should have their "name" and "path" rewritten based on how deep down the tree they are. Example:

```
let result = [
    {
        name: 'dashboard',
        path: '/dashboard',
        id: 'my-dashboard-id',
        someotherprop: someothervalue
        ...
    },
    {
        name: 'dashboard.settings',
        path: '/dashboard/settings',
        id: 'my-settings-id',
        someotherprop: someothervalue
        ...
    },
    {
        name: 'dashboard.settings.user',
        path: '/dashboard/settings/user',
        id: 'my-user-id',
        someotherprop: someothervalue
        ...
    },
    {
        name: 'dashboard.settings.email',
        path: '/dashboard/settings/email',
        id: 'my-email-id',
        someotherprop: someothervalue
        ...
    },
    {
        name: 'dashboard.settings.email.template',
        path: '/dashboard/settings/email/template',
        id: 'my-template-id',
        someotherprop: someothervalue
        ...
    },
    {
        name: 'dashboard.settings.email.template.error',
        path: '/dashboard/settings/email/template.error',
        id: 'my-error-id',
        someotherprop: someothervalue
        ...
    },
    .....
]
```

Thanks

Comment: Please include all relevant information in the question instead of linking to other sites.

Comment: Here on SO, your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Two reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put all relevant code and such (ideally an [mcve]) **in** the question. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/)

Comment: Okay, so see my updated answer.

Comment: FYI, you can use Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button) for runnable examples. [Here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).

Comment: btw, you have an error between template and lists. you need to end the last object and a new object, like `}, {`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take an iterative and recursive approach by handing over the last `name` and `path` to the nested objects.

```js
function getFlat(array, n = '', p = '') {
    return array.reduce((r, { children = [], ...o }) => {
        var name = n + (n && '.') + o.name,
            path = p + o.path;
        return r.concat(Object.assign({}, o, { name, path }), getFlat(children, name, path));
    }, []);
}

var routes = [{ name: 'dashboard', path: '/dashboard', children: [{ name: 'settings', path: '/settings', children: [{ name: 'user', path: '/user' }, { name: 'email', path: '/email', children: [{ name: 'template', path: '/template', children: [{ name: 'error', path: '/error' }, { name: 'success', path: '/success' }] }, { name: 'lists', path: '/lists', children: [{ name: 'signup', path: '/signup' }, { name: 'newsletter', path: '/newsletter' }] }, { name: 'sender', path: '/sender' }] }] }, { name: 'contact', path: '/contact', children: [{ name: 'person', path: '/person', children: [{ name: 'john', path: '/john' }, { name: 'jane', path: '/jane' }] }] }] }],
    flat = getFlat(routes);

console.log(flat);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Really nice. However, the value for item "dashboard" is not included, or "dashboard.settings" either. Maybe I was not clear enough, sorry.

Comment: Ah, great! This looks really good. How would I go to rewrite each object? Like for example, /sender should now instead be /dashboard/settings/email/sender on its property.. ? (As well with the name property, but instead based on its name, separated with a dot)

Comment: please add the wanted outcome to the question. do you like to mutate the data, or get new arrays/objects?

Comment: Ah, sorry. It could acutally be either way, I guess mutate could be better in this case. I have updated the question with hopefully good enough explanation of what I would like to achieve.

Comment: Nina, I noticed you updated your answer. What I meant was to keep the flat structure, so no children array, but all other properties should be kept and name and path should be rewritten to their hierarchy... sorry. Hope you have the energy to look at it again ;)

Comment: i have no idea, what you want. please add the result in object literal form (not prosa) to the question.

Comment: It is almost there? Only noticed the path / name will is not correct once children are on the same level? Like for example "john" and "jane", now "jane" acts like a child of "john", which it shouldn't...

Comment: You're amazing. Thank you. Impressed how you solved this.